# Making a UITableViewCell that is rounded but only on one end

Tags: swift, uitableview

I have a problem in swift. I am trying to make a tableViewCell that is rounded but only on one end. I know how to make rounded tableViewCells with cornerRadius but I want the effect to be only applied to the beginning of the tableViewCell and the end to be standard.

[image: This is basically what I am trying to achieve]

at the moment with the code extensions below I am getting this:
[image: currently what I am getting is this my cell is getting clipped]

```
import UIKit
import SwipeCellKit

class CategoryTableViewCell: SwipeTableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var categoryNameLabel: UILabel!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        roundCorners([.topLeft, .bottomLeft], radius: self.bounds.height / 2)
}

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // Configure the view for the selected state
    }
}

extension UIView {
    func roundCorners(_ corners: UIRectCorner, radius: CGFloat) {
        let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.bounds, byRoundingCorners: corners, cornerRadii: CGSize(width: radius, height: radius))
        let mask = CAShapeLayer()
        mask.path = path.cgPath
        self.layer.mask = mask
    }
}
```

Comment: you can add a view in your tableview at down side so your downside corners don't show in your app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add extension to UIView :

```
extension UIView {
    func roundCorners(_ corners: UIRectCorner, radius: CGFloat) {
        let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.bounds, byRoundingCorners: corners, cornerRadii: CGSize(width: radius, height: radius))
        let mask = CAShapeLayer()
        mask.path = path.cgPath
        self.layer.mask = mask
    }
}
```

Now you can do rounded corner of any corner of the view as per below example.

```
myView.roundCorners([.topLeft,.topRight,.bottomRight], radius: 10)
```

Comment: This would be perfect but it clips the other side of the tableviewcell as well plus the tableViewCell's height shrunk and now there is a white gap between the tableViewCells

Comment: Still didn't get your point, can you please display some graphical like screenshot or design.

Comment: I have added it just now. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Cell height is proper I think can you please check the height of your inner view.

Comment: Thanks I have got it. I was using a xib file for the first time to design the cell but it not working as it should. The only trouble I have now that when i swipe left or right the icon is not showing up from SwipeCellKit

Answer (score 2):

first you have to decide which one to be rounded.

```
extension UIView {
    func bottomRoundCorners(_ corners: UIRectCorner, radius: CGFloat) {
        let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.bounds, byRoundingCorners: corners, cornerRadii: CGSize(width: radius, height: radius))
        let mask = CAShapeLayer()
        mask.path = path.cgPath
        self.layer.mask = mask
    }

    func topRoundCorners(_ corners: UIRectCorner, radius: CGFloat) {
        let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.bounds, byRoundingCorners: corners, cornerRadii: CGSize(width: radius, height: radius))
        let mask = CAShapeLayer()
        mask.path = path.cgPath
        self.layer.mask = mask
    }
}
```

I will apply the sample collectionViewCell class code as follows

```
func configureCell(withBottomCorner bottomCorner: Bool) {
    if bottomCorner == true {
        self.contentView.clipsToBounds = true
        setBottomCorner()
   }
}

func setBottomCorner() {
   if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
      self.contentView.layer.cornerRadius = 6
        self.contentView.layer.maskedCorners = [.layerMaxXMaxYCorner, .layerMinXMaxYCorner]
    } else {
        self.contentView.bottomRoundCorners([.bottomLeft, .bottomRight], radius: 6.0)
    }
 }
```

hope this help.